# Get data from REST API to jsreports

Tags: javascript, rest, jsreport

I could successfully get data from the following script and show in report.

```
function beforeRender(done){
    require("request")({url:"http://nicolas.kruchten.com/pivottable/examples/mps.json",json:true},function(err, response, body){
        request.data = {posts:body};
        done();
    })    
}
```

I used this,

```
<h1>Request</h1>

<table style='border-style:solid'>
  <tr>
    <th>Province</th>
    <th>Party</th>
    <th>Name</th>
  </tr>
  {{for posts}}
  <tr>
    <td>{{:Province}}</td>
    <td>{{:Party}}</td>
    <td>{{:Name}}</td>
  </tr>  
  {{/for}}    
</table>
```

But when I call a REST api using following query it gets data and writes in console but does not show in report.

```
var request = require('request');

function beforeRender(done){
    require('request')({headers: {
    'sToken': 'qq',
    'log': 'dd'
  }, url: 'http://localhost:3000/com.dd.com/Inventory' , json:true },
    function(error, response, body) {
        request.data = {posts:body};
         console.log(request.data );
        done();
    });
}
```

HTML code

```
<h1>Request</h1>
<table style='border-style:solid'>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
  </tr>
   {{for posts}}
  <tr>
    <td>{{:Name}}</td>
  </tr>  
    {{/for}}    
</table>
```

JSON string returned:

```
{ posts:
   { Id: '700',
     Name: 'myName',
     __osHeaders:
      { Version: '{EFF95F4C-2FA2-11E5-BA94-040150C75001}',
        Namespace: 'com.dd.com',
        Class: 'Inventory',
        Tenant: '123',
        LastUdated: '2015-07-21 08:20:56.197248204 -0400 EDT' } } }
```

Engine used: jsrender

 Recipe: phantom-pdf

How can I display the values in Report? Where have I gone wrong when using the API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue. I commented out the following line which caused me not to print it on the report.

```
var request = require('request');
```

Therefore the new code is,

```
//var request = require('request');
    function beforeRender(done){
        require('request')({headers: {
        'sToken': 'qq',
        'log': 'dd'
      }, url: 'http://localhost:3000/com.dd.com/Inventory' , json:true },
        function(error, response, body) {
            request.data = {posts:body};
             console.log(request.data );
            done();
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The first mentioned API returns an array which then works with jsrender `for` loop.

But according to your posted JSON string the second API returns a single object and that is why the `for` loop doesn't work there. It would work without for loop with: `<h1>{{:posts.Name}}</h1>`

So the solution is to change the API call to actually receive an array or convert the output to it so you can loop over.

Comment: I tried both the ways bot got failed. When I removed `for` loop for the second API and added as you said `<h1>{{:posts.Name}}</h1>` It gave this error:  `Error occured - Error during rendering report: Cannot read property 'Name' of undefined
Stack - Error: Cannot read property 'Name' of undefined
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (D:\SW\jsreport\node_modules\script-manager\lib\manager-processes.js:38:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at handleMessage (child_process.js:324:10)
    at Pipe.channel.onread (child_process.js:352:11)
From previous event:
    at Reporter.render`

Comment: I tried to replicate this in the playground https://playground.jsreport.net/#playground/Zys1MkH0rl/3 and it seems to work as I said, can you check it?

Comment: Strange. It works for me in my environment when I add the data as you did in a script. But when I change ONLY the script  to my REST calling script it gives the error.

Comment: Is it really a JSON object what is returned in body? You can try something like JSON.parse on it....

Comment: Yes I used an online validator to validate it, its an JSON object. When I used JSON.parse it gave this error: `Error occured - Error during rendering report: Unexpected token o
Stack - Error: Unexpected token o`